# incrementing array list by a certain value?

Tags: java, list

I have a sorted array list and I want to increment all values by a certain value So how is the code gone be look like..

for instance the List contains 10, 20, 30, 40, 50

for example If incrementing each of them by 5 result would be 15, 25, 35, 45, 55

Comment: Are you using java 8?

Comment: no only simple java code

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I tried to develop this method:-  public void incrementing(int x) {                    } however I don't know what to point to inside the for loop

Comment: Don't replace your question with text saying ["thanks Ive done it"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46878468/revisions): accept an answer. Even if you worked it out after answering the question, people have put effort into replying. Show some appreciation, click the tick.

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8, you can use a (more functional) alternative to the iterative solution by using [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
incrementedList = list.stream()
                      .map(i -> i+5)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could go over the list and set each element with an incremented one:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); ++i) {
    myList.set(i, myList.get(i) + 5);
}
```

Comment: what If I wanted to make it as a method void

Comment: @b7sn This snippet changes the list in-place. You can just declare a method that receives a List argument and modifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:

```
list.replaceAll(i -> i + 5);
```

Comment: I'm trying to develop this method:-  public void incrementing(int x) {                    }

Comment: Ok, so replace `5` with `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to do this:

```
/**
 * Increment all values in the passed in List by a certain value.
 * 
 * @param list - the List to modify the values with.
 * @param increment - how much to increment each value in the list.
 */
public void incrementList (final List<Integer> list, final int increment)
{ 
    if (increment < 1)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("increment must be positive");
    }

    if (list == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("list cannot be null");
    }

    // go through each element and add the increment to each value
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        final int currentValue = list.get(i);
        final int newValue = currentValue + increment;

        list.set(i, newValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@b7sn - So I see that you're trying to write a method called incrementing.

In order to do that, you could use the solution that @shmosel gave, like the following. You will need to pass both the list and x (the increment value) as parameters, so something like this:

```
public void incrementing(List<Integer> list, int x) {
    list.replaceAll(i -> i + x);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A pre-Java 8 way to do it in place:

```
for (ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  it.set(it.next() + 5);
}
```

Note that this is generally more efficient than iterating by index (`list.get(i), list.set(i, ...)`) because it works efficiently on non-`RandomAccess` lists like `LinkedList`.

Comment: You mean pre-Java 8?

Comment: @shmosel well, it'll *also* work in pre-Java 7...

Comment: Well, not if it's pre-Java 5...

Comment: @shmosel I'm not going to use raw types just to get it working back to 1.2...